# CSS: Align div content with underlying container

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment

This is a tough one to explain, so I'll try to visualize it for you. I'd like to use Bootstrap for responsive design.

My problem is that I'd like a div to start at the left edge of the browser. **I'd like it's contents to start in line with the main container**.

`---------------------------------------------------------
|          |                                  |          |
|------------------------                     |          |
|           PAGE TITLE   |                    |          |
|------------------------                     |          |
|          |                                  |          |
|          |                                  |          |
|          |          MAIN CONTAINER          |          |
|          |                                  |          |
|          |                                  |          |`

Any ideas on how to achieve this positioning of `PAGE TITLE`?

Comment: Main container is centered and has fixed width, right?

Comment: Yes, main container is centered and had a fixed width.

Comment: than just put `page title` inside `main container` no?

Comment: I just noticed it's to start inline with main container. Will it stop when the container stops or continue into the right container?

Comment: I have revised my answer, please recheck my codepen. http://codepen.io/Leth0_/pen/zhEtF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you want. :)

I used absolute positioning and fixed right position from the right edge of main container to make the page title start from the left content edge.

**CSS**

```
html, body {height:100%}
#container {
  position:relative; /* note */
  width:600px;
  margin:0 auto;
  padding:80px 20px 0;
  background:#fff;
  min-height:100%;
  border:0 1px;
}
#title {
  position:absolute;
  width:1600px; /* should enough long to always reach left edge in any screen size */
  top:0;
  right:340px; /* note */
  padding:10px 0;
  font-size:2em;
  background:#000;
  color:#999;
}

#title div {
  float:right; /* note */
  width:300px; /* note */
  text-align:left;
}
#title div:after {
  clear:right
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
  <h1 id="title">
    <div>Page title</div>
  </h1>
  <p>Main content</p>
</div>
```

Demo : http://jsbin.com/bideravu/1/edit

This is just an example, you can change any values.

Comment: This is perfect, FYI, the only value that needs changing is `#title { right:1600px}`. This should be set with every new media query. 
Oh, and I changed `#title div { width:300; }` to `padding:0 20px 0 0;` This way, you don't have to change that value as well with each new query.

Answer (score 0):

How about this? You need to use absolute positioning.

http://codepen.io/Leth0_/pen/zhEtF

Hopefully I've understood you correctly.

**CSS**

```
.main{
  position:relative;
}
.left{
    height:100vh;
  border:solid;
  background:#aa6600;
}
.middle{
    height:100vh;
  border:solid;
  background:#aa4422;
}
.right{
    height:100vh;
  border:solid;
  background:#aa6600;
}
.title{
    font-size:3em;
  position:absolute;
  display:block;
  top:50px;
  left:0px;
  z-index:1;
  background:red;
  border:solid;
  height:10vh;
}
```

**HTML**

```
 <div class="main">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-offset-3 title">Title goes here!</div>
    <div class="left col-xs-3"></div>
  <div class="middle col-xs-6"></div>
  <div class="right col-xs-3"></div>
</div>
```

The text size may need changed, I'm using 3em on 1440 x 900. Ideally you'd want to use ~6vmin but it's not widely supported in some browsers. http://caniuse.com/viewport-units

If you don't mind you can change `3em` to `6vmin`

Comment: Sorry, this solution seems to keep the page title within the main container. I only looked at the code pen and saw the wrong behavior, I haven't tinkered with it. Thanks for trying tho!